# Display a menu when hovering on the last character in the input in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am currently working on a form using React-Bootstrap that has a body that takes a message. This message shall include some tags selected from a dropdown menu. The thing is, this dropdown is to be displayed when the user enters an & and then, the user chooses an option from the menu that will replace the ampersand. I handled almost everything except the part of displayed the menu. How can I always show the menu at the last character entered by the user and also, how can I display it when hovering on this character. For example,

"Hi Dear, today we are going to work on &[The menu has to be displayed here when hovering on the ampersand]"

To be honest, I am quite confused and I just need to figure out how I should start. If there could be anything that helps, I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: hey i havent learned react but can i ask a question, maybe i could help.

Comment: @ZiaAhmad Sure you can.

Comment: ok, to make it simple, you want to display a dropdown menu when users enter "'&" in an input field. right?

Comment: @ZiaAhmad Yes. But I want that menu to be always next to the last character entered by the user.

Comment: Saif, i made something, is this what you need?
https://jsfiddle.net/ziaalich/zn74tfeq/8/

Comment: @ZiaAhmad Yes exactly. I will move it to my ReactJS project so that I can use it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: sure, should i post an answer with some details? you can mark that as solved and other people can see it as well

Comment: @ZiaAhmad Sure. I already applied it with some modifications in my ReactJS project and it worked perfectly. Thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: Just post it with some details below so that I can accept it.

Comment: I am glad it helped you!!! Would love to see project you are working on. Thanks.

Comment: @ZiaAhmad Thank you very much. I am grateful tbh.

Comment: That makes me very happy!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something i came up with.

To achieve this, first thing i thought of was to detect the caret position inside `input` or `textarea`.

I found this library and it worked perfectly.
https://github.com/bubkoo/get-cursor-position

Next task was to figure out how to place a menu inside `input` or `textarea`. For that i simply made a parent `div` and i set input `100% width and height` of it & then we can place using any html tag inside that div using `position: absolute` and it will work like we adding stuff inside `input` tag.

The menu was added with `top` & `left` i got using that library. Rest of the code is basic, you can simple figure that out just checking it below.

Here is the code:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')

function showMenu(element) {
  let lastChar = element.value[element.value.length - 1],
    caret = getCaretCoordinates(element, element.selectionEnd);

  if (lastChar === "&") {
    menu.style.display = 'block';
    menu.style.left = caret.left + 20 + 'px'
    menu.style.top = caret.top + 20 + 'px'
  } else {
    menu.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

function copyText(text) {
  const input = document.querySelector('#input')
  input.value += " " + text
  menu.style.display = 'none'
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 120px;
}

#input {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#input:focus {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
}

.menu li {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background: white;
  ;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <textarea id="input" oninput="showMenu(this)"></textarea>
  <div class="menu">
    <li onclick='copyText(this.innerText)'>Mango</li>
    <li onclick='copyText(this.innerText)'>Banana</li>
    <li onclick='copyText(this.innerText)'>Apple</li>
    <li onclick='copyText(this.innerText)'>Orange</li>
    <li onclick='copyText(this.innerText)'>Grapes</li>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/component/textarea-caret-position/master/index.js"></script>
```